# Joomla button's doesn't work Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following

Tags: css, joomla, joomla3.0

When i open my joomla site in my button's don't work any more ans css is screwd up.
when open the debug console in chrome i see:

```
Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content    Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-9M5k0vw//OlS2LDUYDRrGvJ3jT8HdHLh4Tdu4qDFZ7U='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Does any know how to fix this ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The isue was header filter in apache site configuration after remove of this header isue was resolved

Header always set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self';"